# Setting up Laravel-excel and PhpSpreadsheet macro

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I am using Maatwebsite Laravel-excel version 3.1. And I want to set the default styling of the sheet. I have read the documentation about including a macro in your laravel app by setting this in my AppServiceProvider boot() method. :

```
Sheet::macro('getDefaultStyle',function(Sheet $sheet){
        $sheet->getDefaultStyle();
    });
```

But when everytime i reload the page it crashes the page and the laravel server in my cmd stops and re run. Here is my Export.php looks like:

```
 public function registerEvents():array 
{
    return[
        AfterSheet::class=>function(AfterSheet $event){

    $header_style_array = [
        'font'=>['bold'=>true]
    ];
    $style_array = [
        'font'=>['bold'=>true]
    ];
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:B1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:B1')->applyFromArray($header_style_array);
            $event->sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(5);
    }];
}
```

I already included `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents; use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;` above my Export.php file.

Is there something that I missed? I find this so hard to set up. And there's little article about setting this up.

Any help would be much appreciated
Refs: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the documentation for PhpSpreadsheet, I think you will find that the `getDefaultStyle()` method is not accessible from the active sheet.

To Laravel Excel, `$event->sheet` is equivalent to `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()`. This is why your current configuration will not work.

```php
// this doesn't work
// $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(5);

// this does
$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(5);
```

You should set default styles through the writer in `BeforeWriting`.

```php
public function registerEvents():array
{
    return [
        BeforeWriting::class=>function(BeforeWriting $event){
            $event->writer->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(5);
        },
    ];
}
```

If you want to turn this into a macro, you should use a `Writer` macro rather than a `Sheet` macro.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#writer

```php
public function registerEvents():array
{
    Writer::macro('setDefaultStyle', function (Writer $writer) {
        $writer->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(5);
    });

    return [
        BeforeWriting::class=>function(BeforeWriting $event){
            $event->writer->setDefaultStyle();
        },
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering though i haven't tried this yet.